# Streaming data to clients using html 5 audio tag. Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, audio, audio-streaming

I can currently stream data to a client from an HTTP GET, example below.

```
<audio src="http://localhost:5000/Radio_stream.wav" autoplay type="audio/wav" preload="none">
  <p>If your browser doesn't support the 'audio' element</p>
</audio>
```

I have asked several times but nobody seems to answer or understand my problem.

From this GET request I get two different reactions depending on the client.

Firefox : `Correctly` plays the received wav_file as it is streamed, and works perfectly fine.

Chrome : Does `NOT` play the wav_file as it is streamed, instead collects all of the file data until the `connection is dropped`, and then `finally plays the file perfectly` when the connection is dropped.

I am live streaming the wav_file from a live recording, the audio_data is being generated on the fly and sent over. I cannot have chrome collect it until the connection is dropped.

Why does chrome not play the file as it is received, when firefox can??

Edit : Example server code using a python library called flask

```
class wavFileStream(Resource):

    def gen(self):
        global 20_ms_audio

        yield self.createWAVEHeader()

        while True:
              yield 20_ms_audio

    def get(self):
        return Response(self.gen(), mimetype='audio/wav',
                        direct_passthrough=True)
```

Comment: WAV is not all that well supported, unfortunately.

Comment: Sadly true, but I've found working streamed examples such as https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/sounds/music/africa-toto.wav and tried copying every little detail but it still will not "stream"

Comment: Does your client support range requests?

Comment: I have never used them before, but my client would be any browser in a desktop or mobile device. Since it's in HTTP, I would assume so. Anything is worth trying at this point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant *server*.  Does your server support range requests?

Comment: I am not too familiar with range requests. I use a python library called flask, I will add example code in my question.

Comment: have you explored  webrtc protocol for browser to browser audio communication? https://webrtc.org/.